# How to make it in order

Tags: java, printf, vertical-alignment

```
public static void verticalNumber(int n) {
    while (n > 0) {
        n /= 10;
        System.out.printf("%d\n", n % 10);

    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    verticalNumber(1234);
}
```

I want to display the number (1234) like this

```
1

2

3

4
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: 1 problem is n/=10. this means n= 123 then you print n%10 which is 3. the 4 is gone forever never to be heard from again. you need to %10. push answer to stack then /10 and repeat all digits parsed.

Comment: Well you need to maintain the rest of the value (what you do) as well as calculate the current digit to display (what you not do).

Answer (score 1):

You are going on the right direction. However, if you do `n/=10` before the print you are already losing the last digit (`1234` will become `123`) and the following line will print `3`.

If you invert the two lines on the while you will print it vertically. However, it will be upside down. Then you can rotate the monitor to see in the right order (just kidding).

The simplest way possible I can think is to throw the `n%10` result to a list and then add another loop to print it in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

create a list and while ur number is not 0 ;add number mod 10 to it, and number become number div 10, finaly  , u ll have a list that contain ur number in this order 4,3,2,1 , use boocle start from the size of the list and goes to 0 to display their content

Answer (score 0):

`n/=10` needs to go after the printf.
Alternately, you can do:

```java
String.valueOf(n).chars().mapToObj(Character::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

// If you need the extra newlines:
String.valueOf(n).chars().mapToObj(Character::toString).map(c->c+"\n").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, imho, is to convert it to a `String`, convert the `String` to single-character `Strings` and then convert these individual digits (as `Strings`) back to `ints` and store them in an `Array`. Like this:

```
public static void verticalNumber(int n) {
    int[] nums = Arrays.stream(Integer.toString(n).split(""))
            .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
            .toArray();
    for (int num: nums) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

So:

- `1234` becomes `"1234"`
- `"1234"` becomes `["1", "2", "3" "4"]`
- `["1", "2", "3" "4"]` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`